# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime', convert datatype for a specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am new in ASP.NET AND C#.
I would like to know how to convert one field from string to DataTime.

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
string[] Fields;

//Remove Header line
Lines = Lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
List<CountTable> emList = new List<CountTable>();
foreach (var line in Lines)
{
    Fields = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    emList.Add(
        new CountTable
        {
            CountID = Fields[0].Replace("\"", ""),
            Date = Fields[1].Replace("\"", ""),
            UserID = Fields[2].Replace("\"", ""),
            PrinterID = Fields[3].Replace("\"", ""),
            Color = Fields[4].Replace("\"", ""),
            BW = Fields[5].Replace("\"", ""),
        });
}
```

I got this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

at this line

```
Date = Fields[1].Replace("\"", ""),
```

Can any one help me me with the syntax how to solve the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to convert the string to a DateTime object?

See code below:

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName); string[] Fields;
//Remove Header line
Lines = Lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
List<CountTable> emList = new List<CountTable>();
foreach (var line in Lines)
{
    Fields = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    emList.Add(
        new CountTable
        {
            CountID = Fields[0].Replace("\"", ""),
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Fields[1].Replace("\"", "")),
            UserID = Fields[2].Replace("\"", ""),
            PrinterID = Fields[3].Replace("\"", ""),
            Color = Fields[4].Replace("\"", ""),
            BW = Fields[5].Replace("\"", ""),
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` cannot be implicitly cast to `DateTime`. You have to use `DateTime.Parse()` to explicitly convert `string` to `DateTime`.

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(Fields[1].Replace("\"", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `string` to `DateTime` explicitly. I'd suggest using [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This line

```
Date = Fields[1].Replace("\"", ""),
```

should be changed to this

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Fields[1].Replace("\"", ""), "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
```

Please note that with the above code I asssume that the date from the file has `MM/dd/yyyy` format i.e `02/20/2014`. If it has another format then you must change `"MM/dd/yyyy"` to the other format.